# Getting "ERROR 000999: Failed to get raster"?

Tags: arcpy, mosaic

I'm trying create a raster with

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management
```

and this message appears in the end of the process:

> *Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 12384, in
>   MosaicToNewRaster     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000999: Failed to
>   get raster. Please check if the input parameters is correct. Failed to
>   execute (MosaicToNewRaster).*

My script is like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management("SG-21-Z-D.tif;SG-22-Y-C.tif;SH-21-X-B.tif;SH-22-V-A.tif", "marco", "marco.tif", "#", "#", "1", "BLEND", "#")
```

Should I change something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a file geodatabase as your workspace, which can't house `tifs`. Set your workspace to the folder containing the `tifs` or remove the .tif if the rasters are in your geodatabase.